# In general: How to catch subscription errors?

Tags: ros, subscribe, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do i catch errors from subscribers, or even better in general. Originally I tried to catch only subscription errors but as I moved on how to do catch ros exceptions in general as its done in c++ via `(...)`

e.g. InvalidNameException & ConflictingSubscriptionException

```
try{  for (unsigned i=0; i<strVec.size(); i++){
 
    //subscribe stuff
}
} catch (...)
    { //how to catch here, like e.what() in c++
        exit(1);
    }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225968/in-general:-how-to-catch-subscription-errors?/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-02-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unitl the guidelines are [updated](http://wiki.ros.org/CppStyleGuide#Exceptions), I do it like so:
e.g. tf can throw [these](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf/html/c++/exceptions_8h_source.html), so I check for:

```
try
{
    // lookupTransform of tf
}
catch ( const tf2::TransformException& e )
{
    // handle custom exception
}
catch ( const tf2::LookupException& e )
{
    // handle custom exception
}
catch ( const tf2::ConnectivityException& e )
{
    // standard exceptions
}
catch ( ... )
{
    // everything else
}
```

In general simply by this, because

> All of roscpp's exceptions inherit from a common ros::Exception base class.

```
   try
    {
        // throws something
    }
    catch ( ros::Exception &e )
    {
     ROS_ERROR("Error occured: %s ", e.what());
    }
```

---

Originally posted by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) with karma: 748 on 2016-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0